# How to remove doublequotes from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am working on an input for a site which will generate a div tag and its appropriate child elements needed for the website to complete its function. So my ultimate questions are as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="head">
    <title>Question Recall</title>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="body">
    <p>Input File Path: </p><input type="text" id="filepath" value='"C:\Users\Christopher\Desktop\recall.js"'>
    <input type="button" onclick="startgame()" value="Ok">
    <input type="button" onclick="update()" value="Update">
    <p id="quiztitle"></p>
</body>
<script>
    $('#filepath').splice

    function startgame() {
        var filesrc = document.getElementById("filepath").value;
        var gamefile = document.createElement('script');
        gamefile.setAttribute('src', filesrc);
        document.head.appendChild(gamefile);
    };
    function update() {
        $(".question").remove();
        for (var qgs=1; qgs <= tq; qgs++) {
            $("body").append('<div id="q' + (qgs) + '" class="question"><h2 class="questionnum">Question ' + (qgs) + '</h2><br /><p class="question' + (qgs) + '"></p></div>');
        };
    };
</script>
</html>
```

~~Problem~~
When trying to use the type="file" attribute for uploading the recall file happens and get the error the file is not found so I am stuck to using the type="text" attribute. These are where my questions will stem from.

A) Due to javascript not having the permissions of accessing the file system, would there be a way I could have the "file" attribute and it still validate through as a proper script src=""?

or

B) Is there a way to automatically remove the doublequotes (") at the ending and beginning of the input box either via splice or disabling keychars, or even if you know a better function of doing as such. Keep in mind this will be a pasted field.

***Also the script tags after the body will be moved to a dedicated file for them but for the ease of showing this and editing I just made the javascript in the html document***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#filepath').on('input',function(){
   $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/"/g,'') );
});
```

You can use on input and use regex to remove all " in your input and put back the string

Comment: Thank you so much! I have racked my brain trying to figure this one out and at least spent a day searching on this site for a solution :)